# Tensorflow Vector Rank / Dimensions

Tags: tensorflow

In Tensorflow, does a vector of N elements have `shape(0,N)` or `(1,N)`?

I am feeding a vector to a placeholder but am getting this error:

`ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 984) for Tensor u'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(0, 984)'`

Is this the type of situation where `tf.expand_dims` is needed to add a "phantom" dimension to the vector?

**Background**:  I train my model with many examples, in batches. I save the trained model to a checkpoint. Then I restore the model from checkpoint and run it on a single example, in feed-forward inference mode (no training), with batch size = 1. Apparently this issue arises from having 1 input example vs. many. The placeholder:

```
images_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(shared.batchSize, IMAGE_PIXELS))
```

Comment: I am not too familiar with tensorflow but I think you should have the dimensions of the form `(samples, first_dim, second_dim, channels)` (this is in case of multi-channel images). So, when there is only one sample, have you forgotten the first `samples` dimension. It will be 1.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `shape=(1, x)` you do not create a vector, you create a matrix, with one row and `x` columns. To create a vector, use `shape=(x,)`. Take a look at this example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.ones((1, 3))
b = tf.ones((3,))
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print sess.run(a)
    print sess.run(b)
```